# implementing exact full text search in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed few resume in elastic search. So when I am searching for text basically employeeid : "IIIPL-4309". It is giving result for all "IIIPL-xxxx".
How can I restrict the search result to just "IIIPL-4309?

I have tried with custom analyzer

Comment: Please share the mapping and query you tried. You might want to use term query on keyword field. But share those details to get a clear picture

Comment: http://localhost:9200/isearch/_search?q="IIIPL-4309"... This is the get query.. ao instead of getting result for only just "IIIPL-4309" I am getting for all id's "IIIPL-XXXX"

Comment: This actually runs a `query string` query. Check the answer below to get the desired result.

Comment: My superviser advised me to use analyzer. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: I don't think in your case you need a special custom analyzer as ES by default provides the keyword field and you need to search for exact text. Do you need case insensitive search ? In that case you might need one, as by default standard analyzer will tokenize `IIIPL-4309` into `IIPL` and `4309` and will split on hyphen.

Comment: not special custom analyzer. There is keyword analyzer in elastic search. However I observed that using term query on keyword we are getting exact match and in kibana we have to use quotes around phrase for exact match.

Comment: Actually the problem is with kibana search. There we have to enclose the phrase in quotes for exact match. But we want some provision which will give exact match without enclosing the phrase in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to search with exact match you should go with [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) on the keyword field like this

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "someField.keyword": {
                "value": "IIIPL-4309"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so do I need to reindex the document and then try term query. How to implement it as I looking the result in kibana?

Comment: What is your current mapping ?

Comment: if I reindex then in kibana graphs are pointing to old index then it will be problem from kibana end as It should point to new index now. Is there any turnaround without reindexing or programatically by calling some api can be done. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please share your current mapping. May be you don't have to change it if the field you are searching on is `text` . Query to get mapping is `GET index_name/_mapping`

Comment: {
    "testisearch-mis": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "EDUCATION_RESUME": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },

Comment: actually in my application I am uploading resume through portal which then indexes it in elastic search. The _id is of the format of employee id that is "IIIPL-XXXX" format. But suppose when I search for resume in kibana with id "IIIPL-4309" it is giving result for all the resume which matches "IIIPL". So I need exact match. So from api side I am getting the exact match that is term query on keyword as you suggested but from kibana ui I am not getting the exact match.

Comment: but I get exact match in kibana when I wrap the text in double qoutes.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `exact match`. You would need to use [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) type in elasticsearch in order to achieve that.

From the link,

> They are typically used for filtering (Find me all blog posts where
>   status is published), for sorting, and for aggregations. Keyword
>   fields are only searchable by their exact value.

Below is how the mapping would be, I'm just creating a sibling field for the `employee_id` as `employee_id.keyword`

### Mapping:

```
PUT employee
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "properties":{  
         "employee_id":{  
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{  
               "keyword":{  
                  "type":"keyword"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Sample Documents

```
POST employee/_doc/1
{
  "employee_id": "IIIPL-4309"
}

POST employee/_doc/2
{
  "employee_id": "IIIPL-4229"
}
```

### Query

```
POST employee/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "employee_id.keyword": "IIIPL-4309"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: so do I need to reindex the document and then try term query. How to implement it as I looking the result in kibana?

Comment: Yup, you would have to reindex the documents. Make sure to change the mapping though. In the kibana, you just have to use the keyword field. It'll work.

Comment: but it is working without re indexing as I have checked it using above query and its working fine.

Comment: ahh, that is because you may not have created the mapping explicitly, elasticsearch by default creates two fields a `text` and a `keyword` for every string data you ingest if you do not specify the mapping, in short elasticsearch has a concept of creating mapping dynamically if you do not specify mapping.

Comment: if I reindex then in kibana graphs are pointing to old index then it will be problem from kibana end as It should point to new index now. Is there any turnaround without reindexing or programatically by calling some api can be done. Please help me with this.

Comment: Here is what you can do, Use `Reindex API`, take a back up of existing index in `backup_index_name`. Have Kibana point to this index. Delete the existing index, create it back with the mapping you need and then insert the new data into this. Again change Kibana to point to this original index. But I'm a little confused you said your query was working without reindexing, so why would you need to go through all this? Could you clarify what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: actually in my application I am uploading resume through portal which then indexes it in elastic search. The _id is of the format of employee id that is "IIIPL-XXXX" format. But suppose when I search for resume in kibana with id "IIIPL-4309" it is giving result for all the resume which matches "IIIPL". So I need exact match.

Comment: So from api side I am getting the exact match that is term query on keyword as you suggested but from kibana ui I am not getting the exact match.

Comment: Also I get exact match in kibana when I wrap the text I search for in double qoutes.